# How are Durandal and Aurelia related?

Tags: durandal, aurelia

I've been reading about Durandal and Aurelia every time I read something new on Javascript. I hear developers asking to upgrade from Durandal to Aurelia, or similar, on so many blogs. Although I do have an idea, I am confused about what the two really are and how they are related, or if at all they even are related.

Here's how I see it. Durandal is a lightweight SPA framework that allows you to leverage the best of other JS libraries and utilities to  build an app. So it's not really a whole package in itself (unlike Angular), but can use different external JS libs - such as Knockout for binding, jQuery for DOM, Sammy for routing, etc.

Aurelia, on the other hand, is where the confusion comes in. Is it also an SPA framework? Or is it limited to being a client-side (front end) framework only? To add to my confusion there is a [Durandal blog](http://blog.durandal.io/) that talks only about Aurelia. I know from the internet that Rob Eisenberg worked on Durandal before he started working on Aurelia. So is Aurelia an upgrade of Durandal, or something completely unrelated?

I still have some questions but I'm guessing the structure of my question so far will be only asking for opinionated answers. So before this question is closed, any description, links and references in regard will be amazing. I'll be sure to update and add useful links here too.

Comment: To quote Rob, Aurelia is Durandal 2.0

Comment: Aurelia takes Durandal's essence (data-binding, modular javascript, simple conventions) and modernizes it.  Pure ES6/ES7, no dependencies, faster and more powerful templating and data-binding and much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Rob Eisenberg:

"Aurelia is just a vNext of Durandal. On occasion we've even called it Durandal Aurelia. Much like XBox 360 vs. XBox One. The web is significantly evolving, so we're evolving Durandal into Aurelia to match."

> Aurelia, on the other hand, is where the confusion comes in. Is it
>   also an SPA framework? Or is it limited to being a client-side (front
>   end) framework only?

Yes, it is a SPA framework. Actually, it is a framework for building Javascript clients, it means you can develop apps for Browser, Desktop and Mobile. Take a look at this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Seth-on-the-Road/DevIntersection-2015/Rob-Eisenberg-on-Aurelia

Different from Durandal, Aurelia comes with the full package, everything you need is there. However, it is perfectly pluggable and extensible, and you can combine any other technologies if necessary.

---

Here is description provided by the official site [www.aurelia.io](http://www.aurelia.io)

### **What is Aurelia?**

Well, it's actually simple. Aurelia is just JavaScript. However, it's not yesterday's JavaScript, but the JavaScript of tomorrow. By using modern tooling we've been able to write Aurelia from the ground up in ECMAScript 2016. This means we have native modules, classes, decorators and more at our disposal...and you have them too.

Not only is Aurelia written in modern and future JavaScript, but it also takes a modern approach to architecture. In the past, frameworks have been monolithic beasts. Not Aurelia though. It's built as a series of collaborating libraries. Taken together, they form a powerful and robust framework for building Single Page Apps (SPAs). However, Aurelia's libraries can often be used individually, in traditional web sites or even on the server-side through technologies like NodeJS."

---

Some of the greatest advantages of Aurelia (in my opinion) are:

Powerful Data-binding. Different from others frameworks like Angular, Aurelia uses new features of Javascript. So, all data-binding stuffs are usually faster in Aurelia (source http://blog.durandal.io/2015/12/04/aurelia-repaint-performance-rules/)

Simple Conventions and Simple Syntax. It is really easy to develop in Aurelia. There are a lot of features ready to use. If you want to overwrite some convention, usually 1 line of code is enough. (see http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.3/doc/article/getting-started)

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Aurelia is just a vNext of Durandal. Different from Durandal, Aurelia comes with the full package". This helps a lot in understanding Aurelia better now.